# Gforce min not supported for character in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

When trying to take the min of a character vector using data.table 1.9.4, I get the following error:

```
Type 'character' not supported by GForce min (gmin). 
Either add the prefix base::min(.) or turn off 
GForce optimization using options(datatable.optimize=1)
```

Fair enough, but this breaks a lot of my existing code! I can turn off this optimization using `options(datatable.optimize=1)`. Still, is there anyway to simply use `base::min` if `is.character == TRUE`, and GForce optimization otherwise?

Comment: Not directly, not until it's fixed. Sorry. `min/max` on `character` type has totally skipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented in [commit 1734](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/a18d624b40b464ab623e39a4a6cd8de24f8f7131) of [data.table v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5
set.seed(1L)
DT = data.table(x=sample(3,10,TRUE), y=sample(letters[1:3], 10,TRUE))
options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)

DT[, .(min(y), max(y)), by=x]
# Detected that j uses these columns: y 
# Finding groups (bysameorder=FALSE) ... done in 0secs. bysameorder=FALSE and o__ is length 10
# lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(min(y), max(y))'
# GForce optimized j to 'list(gmin(y), gmax(y))'
#    x V1 V2
# 1: 1  a  c
# 2: 2  a  c
# 3: 3  b  c
```

Please write back if something isn't right.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't the data.table.v1.14.2 deal automatically with character type now? I got the same error as the OP's one.