# data.table "list" versus ":=" in dealing with NaN

Tags: r, data.table

Noticed some weird behavior of data.table, hopefully someone who understands data.table better than I can explain.

Say I have this data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  C1 = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B",4), rep("C", 4)),
  C2 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b",3), rep("c",3), rep("d",3)),
  Val = c(1:5, NaN, NaN, 8,9,10,NaN,12))

DT
    C1 C2 Val
 1:  A  a   1
 2:  A  a   2
 3:  A  a   3
 4:  A  b   4
 5:  B  b   5
 6:  B  b NaN
 7:  B  c NaN
 8:  B  c   8
 9:  C  c   9
10:  C  d  10
11:  C  d NaN
12:  C  d  12
```

Now, in my mind, the following two methods should generate the same results, but they do not.

```
TEST1 <- DT[, agg := min(Val, na.rm = TRUE), by = c('C1', 'C2')]
TEST1 <- data.table(unique(TEST1[, c('C1','C2','agg'), with = FALSE]))

TEST2 <- DT[, list(agg = min(Val, na.rm = TRUE)), by = c('C1', 'C2')]

TEST1
   C1 C2 agg
1:  A  a   1
2:  A  b   4
3:  B  b   5
4:  B  c   8
5:  C  c   9
6:  C  d  10


TEST2
   C1 C2 agg
1:  A  a   1
2:  A  b   4
3:  B  b   5
4:  B  c NaN
5:  C  c   9
6:  C  d  10
```

As you can see, using " := " generates a minimum value for (C1 = B, C2 = c) of 8. Whereas the list command results in an NaN.
Funnily enough, for (C1 = B,C2 = b) and (C1 = C, C2 = d), which also have NaNs, the list command does produce a value.
I believe this to be because in the instance where the NaN is first before a value for a given C1 C2 combination, the NaN results. Whereas in the other two examples the NaN comes after a value.

Why does this occur?

I note that if the NaN are replaced with NA then values are generated with no problems.

Comment: no idea but `DT[, list(agg = min(.SD$Val, na.rm = TRUE)), by = c('C1', 'C2')]` also works

Comment: Or `DT[, list(agg=min(c(Val), na.rm=TRUE)), by = .(C1, C2)]`  It is a bit strange, but the equivalent step in `dplyr` works after converting to `data.frame`.

Comment: You should definitely report a bug. I suspect that this is due to the "internal" implementation of `data.table` `min` function. When inside a `data.table` operation, some functions (like `min`, `max` and `sum`) are replaced by faster `data.table` versions. If you call explicitly the `base` function, you get the correct output: `DT[, list(agg = base::min(Val, na.rm = TRUE)), by = c('C1', 'C2')]`. No idea why  `data.table` seems to revert to `base::min` when used in combination with `:=`.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in data.table's optimized version of min and should be reported. To turn that behavior off, use `options(datatable.optimize=1)`. After making a fix, I'm sure one of the data.table authors will post an answer here, as they did last time http://stackoverflow.com/q/27987424/1191259

Comment: Nicola is spot on. Please file as bug. @nicola, what do you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: It was a reference on the fact that the update `DT[, agg := min(Val, na.rm = TRUE), by = c('C1', 'C2')]` seems to work nicely, while the subset `DT[, list(agg = min(Val, na.rm = TRUE)), by = c('C1', 'C2')]` doesn't. Is it because `min` is a different function in the two cases or the error is due to something else?

Comment: @nicola, got it. The former.. `:=` isn't optimised for GForce (internal optimisation) yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed this issue, [#1461](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1461) just now in devel, v1.9.7 with [commit 2080](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/2c02b259090fa9ff60dcf0a347074c784d69d8c0).

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7, commit 2080+
DT <- data.table(
     C1 = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B",4), rep("C", 4)),
     C2 = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b",3), rep("c",3), rep("d",3)),
     Val = c(1:5, NaN, NaN, 8,9,10,NaN,12))

DT[, list(agg = min(Val, na.rm = TRUE)), by = c('C1', 'C2')]
#    C1 C2 agg
# 1:  A  a   1
# 2:  A  b   4
# 3:  B  b   5
# 4:  B  c   8
# 5:  C  c   9
# 6:  C  d  10
```